# How to extract Value from Table (Javascript) in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get a value from a table.

```
transaction: {
        id: 'RST4A5',
        affiliationId: '',
        currency: 'EUR',
        revenue: 105,
        tax: 0,
        products: [
          {
            id: 'H3518/R8242',
            type: 'Room',
            rate: 'BARPALY',
            price: 105,
            currency: 'EUR',
            quantity: 1
          }
        ]
      }
```

I need to create a variable in Google Tag Manager from "rate".
I tried `products[0].price` but still don't work.

Please help

Comment: transaction.products[0].price

Answer (score 0):

GTM uses dot notation to access objects, so you would need to use `products.0.price`. Make sure you define your variable as a "Data Layer Variable" type.